# How can I force an object attribute in Perl to be set to a full array instead of just its length?

Tags: perl

I have an object I defined with a method, childNodes(), which returns an array. When I do something like:
`my @arr = obj->childNodes()` 
I can clearly see that it can properly return an array.

My problem is that when I try to use this method to set the attribute of another class object, Perl decides I just want the length of childNodes() rather than the full array. This is not at all what I want and ruins everything. The code I'm using for this is:
`$self->{'_arr'} = obj->childNodes()`
How can I make this set $self->{'_arr'} to an array instead of just a scalar number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you evaluate an array in scalar context, it returns the length of the array.

You want a reference to the array:

```
$self->{'_arr'} = [ obj->childNodes() ];
```

See [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).

Comment: To expand, Perl hashes can only contain scalars, you cannot have a an array or another hash as a hash member.
References are scalars, even when they refer to non-scalar things, so references can be stored in a hash.